# Python - Unable to upload file to defined folder in AWS S3 bucket

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to upload a csv file from my local to aws s3 bucket. Given below is the code I am using but it doesn't seen to upload the file to the s3 folder defined. Could anyone assist.

```
import boto3
from botocore.client import Config

ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'accesskeyid'
ACCESS_SECRET_KEY = 'secretkeyid'
BUCKET_NAME = 'bucketname'

data = open('/desktop/file.csv', 'rb')

s3 = boto3.resource(
's3',
aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY_ID,
aws_secret_access_key=ACCESS_SECRET_KEY,
config=Config(signature_version='s3v4')
)
s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME).put_object(Key='/sub-folder/sub-folder2/file.csv', Body=data)

print ("Uploaded successfully")
```

Could anyone help me in finding where I am going wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `/` from the beginning of the `Key` argument.

Using your existing code, the file path will be: `BUCKET_NAME//sub-folder/sub-folder2/file.csv`.